# What is a RPI3 "evaluation board"?

Tags: pi-3

When trying to buy a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B from the [official raspberrypi.org products page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/) (using the "or buy for business" link underneath the large "Buy now" button), I get sent to [this specific product](http://uk.farnell.com/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi-modb-1gb/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/dp/2525225) on the UK Farnell Element14 site.

The product description is **RASPBERRYPI3-MODB-1GB -  Evaluation Board, Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, Quad Core 1.2GHz CPU, 1GB RAM, WiFi/BLE, 40 GPIO Pins**.

Why is the RPI described as being an `evaluation board`, and what does that mean exactly? Is there a "regular" board floating around?

Comment: Farnell just call any populated circuit board an 'evaluation board'. That is the correct Pi3 item.

Comment: They probably don't have the category "single-board computers", so I believe "Evaluation Board" is a misnomer since this belongs to the category "Microprocessor development board" and I believe that very few if any use Raspi for developing the on board microprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't different grades of Raspberry Pi, just different models. What many online resellers are doing (including this one) is labelling the board as an "evaluation board" when sold all by itself, instead of a bundle or kit when it ships with a case, power supply, SD card and whatnot.

Comment: I am not aware of there being more than one _model_ of `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B`. Did you meant that there are different _bundles_ sold by resellers?

Comment: @SilviuG There are different models of the Raspberry Pi: model 3B, model 2B, model 1A, model 1B. There are also different bundles sold.

Comment: My question was explicitly about `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B` as specified in the previous comment, but I get your point. Thanks!